# MS SQL case statement and cast/covert data type issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, casting, case

I'm having an issue with the MS SQL case statement that has cast inside. Here is the example I cam up with.

```
DECLARE @bla as varchar(10) = '001234'
DECLARE @vb AS varchar(20) = 'bla'
SELECT CASE when (@vb <> 'bla') THEN CAST(@bla AS int) ELSE @bla END vbla
```

The result is very strange. It should be 001234. What am I missing?

```
+------+
| vbla |
+------+
| 1234 |
+------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `case` EXPRESSION (not statement) returns a single type.  When one of the branches is a number, then the return value is a number.

The value you are seeing is the *number* that the string converts to.  If the string started with a non-digit, then the value would be `0`.

If you want to see the leading zeros, leave the value as a string.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your logic. Are you saying that both THEN and ELSE have to be varchar datatypes?

Comment: @LeoG - The expression `CASE foo THEN this ELSE that END` first needs to determine what data-type it's going to return.  Imagine you wrote that to process a million rows of data from a table; you can't have some results being `INT` and some being `VARCHAR`, they all need to be the same data-type.  So, even though you wrote it with two data-types, the SQL engine needs to work out how to ***implicitly*** force the results to always have the same data-type.  In this case because the `THEN` branch is an `INT`, the SQL engine is going to *implicitly coerce* the `ELSE` branch to also be an `INT`.

Comment: That is what I thought. Thanks